# I am having issues with predicateForConsent function of ORKResultPredicate

Tags: ios, swift, researchkit

When I tap Agree button it should go to consentCompletionStep but it goes to consent disagree Step. Please can anyone point out what is the issue?

```
let consentTask = ORKNavigableOrderedTask(identifier: String(describing:Identifier.consentTask), steps: [reviewConsentStep, disAgreeStep, completionStep])

resultSelector = ORKResultSelector(
    resultIdentifier: String(
        describing: Identifier.consentReviewStep))
let predicateAgree = ORKResultPredicate.predicateForConsent(
    with: resultSelector, didConsent: true)

let agreePredicateRule = ORKPredicateStepNavigationRule(
    resultPredicatesAndDestinationStepIdentifiers: [
        (predicateAgree,
         String(describing: Identifier.consentCompletionStep))])

consentTask.setNavigationRule(
    agreePredicateRule,
    forTriggerStepIdentifier:String(
        describing:Identifier.consentReviewStep))

let consentDirectRule = ORKDirectStepNavigationRule(
    destinationStepIdentifier: ORKNullStepIdentifier)
consentTask.setNavigationRule(
    consentDirectRule,
    forTriggerStepIdentifier:String(
        describing:Identifier.consentDisagreeStep))
```

Comment: Can you reverse this order of adding the `Rule` and check.

Comment: So I moved directRule above the predicateRule, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the resultSelector passed to `+predicateForConsentWithResultSelector:didConsent:` must provide the desired step identifier (stepIdentifier argument) and the desired signature identifier (resultIdentifier argument).

Instead of:

```
let resultSelector = ORKResultSelector(resultIdentifier:String(describing: Identifier.consentReviewStep))
let predicateAgree = ORKResultPredicate.predicateForConsent(with: resultSelector, didConsent: true)
```

It should be:

```
let resultSelector = ORKResultSelector(stepIdentifier: String(describing: Identifier.consentReviewStep), resultIdentifier: signature.identifier)
let predicateAgree = ORKResultPredicate.predicateForConsent(with: resultSelector, didConsent: true)
```